# Realtime illustration of an object in google map using pygmaps (in Python)

Tags: python, pygmaps

I am trying to illustrate a position of an object in google map (in realtime) using pygmaps. I have a database that contains large amount of positioning data (stored as lat and long in ***RouteCoordinationsList***). So far I am able to highlight any specific given route in the map. Now I need to draw an image (like a train or even a dot) each 10ms in the map without reloading the page. With the following code I have to reload the page to see the updates which is totally useless for me:

```
mymap = pygmaps.maps(37.701695, -121.900354,15)
path = RouteCoordinationsList
mymap.addpath(path,"#00FF00")
mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
os.system("open "+'./mymap.html')
for points in path:
    mymap.addpoint(points[0], points[1], "#00FFFF")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**  Here is the solution that I came up with:

https://github.com/hossein1387/BART-System-Verification/tree/master/ComputerSide/PythonCodes/Ver1.0

And here is a link to a video demonstrating how thi project works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO1HBslPy88